# how do I get a specific index within an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

data = [1.3,3.4,5.6........ thousands of data point correlation to specific months.

```
def find_index(month,year):
    year_date = year - 1749
    np.array(data)
    years = np.array_split(data, 234)
    print(years[year_date])

find_index(month,1793) #need to get month index
```

output:
[45.  44.  38.  28.4 55.7 41.5 41.  40.  11.1 28.5 67.4 51.4]

### how do I go about getting a specific index from this output.

Comment: Could you describe a little what is the format of your data and the desire output?

Comment: it is just a list of about 2000 different numbers 1D i think. each number is the data for that month. I want to be able to split the data into specific years and months so then I can input a month and a year and to find the specific index and point from my array. I tried splitng it up in years which I did and is the output but i want to be able to get a specfic number from that output which i dont know how to do

Comment: Ok, now can you provide a little example of some input and the desire output for that input

Comment: data = [66.5, 80.7, 99.2, 91.1, 82.2, 71.8, 50.3, 55.8, 33.3, 33.4, 66.5, 80.7, 99.2, 91.1, 82.2, 71.8, 50.3, 55.8, 33.3, 33.4] ##two years of data 24 points. input 1790(first year index 0-11) and 2(second month feb) so Output = 80.7

Comment: Define a function with month (as numbers 1-12) and year as the parameters, make it
return the index of the data counts in the given month and year.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find_index(array, month, year):
    date_index = (year - 1749) * 12 + month - 1
    date_value = array[date_index]
    return (date_index, date_value)
```

Given the data:

```
data = [66.5, 80.7, 99.2, 91.1, 82.2, 71.8, 50.3, 55.8, 33.3, 33.4,66.5, 80.7, 99.2, 91.1, 82.2, 71.8, 50.3, 55.8, 33.3, 33.4]
```

I get the next results:

```
print(find_index(data, 1, 1749))
print(find_index(data, 6, 1749))
print(find_index(data, 1, 1750))
```

Output (index of array, value)

```
(0, 66.5)
(5, 71.8)
(12, 99.2)
```

I assume the first element of the array corresponds to January 1749

Comment: thank you very much. I had no idea that it was that simple. I guess I was overthinking it.